# archiver_get_archiver() returns FASLE

Tags: files

I was doing some zip processing and came through the code which update_manager_archive_extract() uses. This is the code:-

```
$path_to_zip = '/some-local-path/testfile.zip';

$archiver = archiver_get_archiver($path_to_zip);

$files = $archiver->listContents();

$extract_location = '/some-extract-location/';

 if (file_exists($extract_location)) {
      file_unmanaged_delete_recursive($extract_location);
 }

$archiver->extract($extract_location);
```

I am getting "FALSE" result from archiver_get_archiver(). The $archiver variable is FALSE.

Comment: Per the documentation: _If no appropriate archiver class was found, will return FALSE._

Comment: @Clive I saw the documentation and then i thought that FALSE was returned, but i am giving a path to local zip file like /sites/default/files/test.zip

So, i dont get why it returns FALSE

Comment: Presumably your installation of PHP doesn't include the `zip_open` function, so the zip archiver is not availalbe